# Hi how can I do random operations with flutter?

Tags: android, string, flutter, random, integer

Hi how do I want to show you random city name and time in my application? Different times and cities should appear each time the app is entered?Let me illustrate what I mean: The user entered the application and saw Amsterdam at 23:43 as the time. How can I do if I want the output from the application to appear in the opposite Hague 08:37 when it enters again? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have list of `cities` and list of `times` or you can even generate `time` based on present time.

Sample code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final cities = ['Amsterdam', 'The Hague', 'Rotterdam', 'Utrecht', 'Groningen'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final random = Random(); // You can use random to generate random cities
    final city = cities[random.nextInt(cities.length)];
    final time = DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: random.nextInt(60 * 24)));

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Random City')),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(city, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32)),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              Text('${time.hour.toString()}:${time.minute.toString()}'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```